# proving that a given quotient ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I have to prove that $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+2\rangle$ is a field using the field axioms. I've been able to verify 9 of them but I am having trouble figuring out how to prove the multiplicative inverse. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An element in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]/\left<x^2 + 2\right>$ can be written as $[a + bx]$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. We have

$$ [a + bx] \cdot [a - bx] = [a^2 - b^2 x^2] = [a^2 + 2b^2] $$

so the inverse of $[a + bx]$ should be $\left[\frac{a}{a^2 + 2b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2 + 2b^2}x\right]$. Check that this indeed works (in particular, check that $a^2 + 2b^2 \neq 0$ if $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$).

Comment: Note the similarity of this situation with finding inverses in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

As $x^2+2$ has no root in  $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, it is irreducible in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]$, and $(x^2+2)$ is a prime ideal, hence the quotient ring   $A=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+2)$ is an integral domain.

This means multiplication by any non-zero element $a$ of $A$ is injective and, since $A$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, this multiplication is also surjective; in particular $1$ is attained, i. e. there exists an element $a'$ such that $aa'=1$. Thus any $a\ne 0$ is invertible.

Comment: I think this line of argument can be simplified by noting that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is itself a field. (Then, we can directly apply the theorem which states that a polynomial ring of a field modulo an irreducible polynomial is again a field.)

Comment: I didn't  know what the O. P. was supposed to know, so I sketched the proof that a finite dimensional algebra  over a field,  which is an integral domain is a field.